# How to find Icon names for Font Awesome to import with React?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I have added Font Awesome icon library to my react project. 
As per the documentation, i am creating a library but not able to add icons as i dont know the icon name to import.

For eg - On website icon is "coffee". But to add to library i need to use -

library.add(faCoffee)

then i can use it as -

How do i find the icon React name i.e. faCoffee for coffee?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee);

<FontAwesome icon="coffee" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would consider using [react-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons) over the `@fortawesome` package for popular icon packages.`React-icons` is nice because it provides `ES6` support for various popular icons, allowing one to only include the icons actually being used within your `react` project. Some popular supported icon packages within `react-icons` are the following:

1. Font Awesome
2. Ionicons
3. Material Design Icons
4. Typicons
5. And many more for a complete list look [here](https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/)

For your particular case you could easily use Font Awesome icons and search for the exact name of the icon you're trying to use by doing the following:

1. Install the react-icons package

   `npm install react-icons --save`
2. Search for your desired icon and exact import name [here](https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/icons/fa)
3. Import and use the desired icon within your `react` project, for example the Font Awesome coffee icon:

   `import { FaCoffee } from 'react-icons/fa';
   <FaCoffee />`

The `react-icons` package is extremely easy to use and in my experience has been less complex than the other icon packages for `react` projects.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks. While not the answer i was looking for, this is a better solution overall.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to answer this even though it's old and I'm sure you were able to figure it out, just because NOBODY actually answered your question correctly.

You can find the font awesome icons [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/).

When you click on an icon you'll see the icon name, e.g. 'arrow-circle-left' but in order to use it like in your above example, you'll have to add 'fa' to the start and convert the rest to camel case. I.e. 'arrow-circle-left' becomes 'faArrowCircleLeft'.

You can then import it using:

```js
    import { faArrowCircleLeft } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

No idea why they can't just post a list of these names somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`fa` is a shortform for font awesome i believe. You can find all the icon names from here
[here](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)

If you want to use the icon, all you need to do is append with `fa` while importing and while using it, use it without `fa`.

See sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-mendel-io0nv)

Comment: I can work out a few using obvious conventions , but for others like - file-download ? What convention to follow with '-' ?

Comment: I have updated the above sandbox with `file-download` icon implementation. Have a look @abc

Answer (score 1):

You can find all Fontawesome icons names [here](https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/icons/fa)